# Xcode 7.2 Swift - Cannot drag, drop, move Label on Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I can't seem to move the UILabel. I'm just starting to learn iOS, so I'm sure it's something silly and simple. Help?

[image: UILabel is stuck where the arrow is, can't move it]

Comment: You need to add a view and then you can add elements to that view. Try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `View Controller Scene` doesn't contain a main `UIView`. I don't know how you did that, but either try to drop a `View` instead of a `Label` and see if that worked, or create the `viewcontroller scene`.

Comment: That worked. I just started with a new project --> new single view application, and the UILabel was the first thing I tried to place. I was following a tutorial and apparently in an older version of Xcode, that was possible https://vimeo.com/102084767

Answer (score 0):

Try zooming into the storyboard and then moving the label. Sometimes if you are too far out you won't be able to move individual elements.

Comment: I tried zooming in, but can't zoom in anymore. Already at 100%. I could zoom out, which makes it smaller, but I'm currently already at the biggest view of the screen.

Comment: Delete that label and try placing a new one on the view. Restart xcode before that.

Answer (score 0):

As Rashwan L. pointed out, you have to drag out a UIView from the Object Library first and add it to the View Controller. Then you can drag a UILabel out and add it to the UIView.